# SQL Group By most recent date and sales value

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following sales table that displays the customer ID, their name, the order amount, and the order date.

| ID | Name | Order | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 25 | 11/10/2006 |
| 1 | A | 10 | 5/25/2010 |
| 1 | A | 10 | 6/18/2018 |
| 2 | B | 20 | 3/31/2008 |
| 2 | B | 15 | 11/15/2010 |
| 3 | C | 35 | 1/1/2019 |
| 3 | C | 20 | 4/12/2007 |
| 3 | C | 10 | 3/20/2010 |
| 3 | C | 5 | 10/19/2012 |
| 4 | D | 15 | 12/12/2013 |
| 4 | D | 15 | 2/18/2010 |
| 5 | E | 25 | 12/11/2006 |
| 6 | F | 10 | 5/1/2016 |

I am trying to group the data so that for each customer it would only show me their most recent order and the amount, as per below:

| ID | Name | Order | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 6/18/2018 |
| 2 | B | 15 | 11/15/2010 |
| 3 | C | 35 | 1/1/2019 |
| 4 | D | 15 | 12/12/2013 |
| 5 | E | 25 | 12/11/2006 |
| 6 | F | 10 | 5/1/2016 |

So far I've only been able to group by ID and Name, because adding the Order column would also group by that column as well.

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  Name,
  MAX(Date) 'Most recent date'
FROM Table
GROUP BY Customer, Customer
```

How can I also add the order amount for each Customer?

Comment: top N per group

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Name, Order, Date FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date DESC) AS sn
    FROM your_table_name
) A WHERE sn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for. It makes a lot of sense creating the helper column. Can I just asked what the 'A' does in that last line?

Comment: We have use subquery in our query and subquery always needs alias so A is just alias you can use any name instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subqoery for max date
SELECT
ID,
Name,
MAX(Date) 'Most recent date'
FROM Table
GROUP BY Customer, Customer

```
select a.ID,   a.Name, b.max_date
from Table a 
inner join  (
    select name, max(Date) max_date
    from Table 
    group by name 
) b on a. name  = b.name and a.date = b.max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get the expected result:

```
SELECT S.* 
FROM Sales S
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT ID, Max(Date) MaxDate 
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY ID
)T 
WHERE S.ID = T.ID 
  AND S.Date = T.MaxDate 
ORDER BY S.ID
```